# Not able to find EJB matching "StatelessEJBLocator"

Tags: ejb

I am new to EJB. I created one EJB and deployed it on wildfly server. I wrote a client to get the EJB and invoke methods on it, but it is failing with the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: EJBCLIENT000024: Not able to find EJB matching "StatelessEJBLocator for "/EjbComponent/LibrarySessionBean", view is interface com.tutorialspoint.stateless.LibrarySessionBeanRemote, affinity is None"
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.discoverAffinityNone(EJBClientContext.java:716)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.performLocatedAction(EJBClientContext.java:698)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:146)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:96)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.addBook(Unknown Source)
    at com.tutorialspoint.test.EJBTester.main(EJBTester.java:37)
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: JBREM000202: Abrupt close on Remoting connection 32e5e0c7 to localhost/127.0.0.1:8080 of endpoint (anonymous) <72a094c>
        at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.ClientConnectionOpenListener$Greeting.handleEvent(ClientConnectionOpenListener.java:173)
        at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.ClientConnectionOpenListener$Greeting.handleEvent(ClientConnectionOpenListener.java:162)
        at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
        at org.xnio.conduits.ReadReadyHandler$ChannelListenerHandler.readReady(ReadReadyHandler.java:66)
        at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.handleReady(NioSocketConduit.java:89)
        at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:567)
        at ...asynchronous invocation...(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.connect(EndpointImpl.java:465)
        at org.jboss.remoting3.FutureConnection.getConnection(FutureConnection.java:117)
```